# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED over HTTP but HTTPS works fine

Tags: ubuntu

I dont see why i get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED over http but https works just fine. My virtual hosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName yourdomain.com
Redirect permanent / https://www.yourdomain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

Listen 443 https

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/yourdomain.com/public
ServerName localhost


ErrorLog /var/www/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
# SSL Configuration

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On

SSLCompression Off

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/yourdomain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/yourdomain.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/yourdomain.ca-bundle
ServerSignature Off


<Directory /var/www/yourdomain.com/public>
Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

What am i doing wrong? Also i want to redirect http to https. But its not doing anything at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume in the actual file, the ServerName for *:80 is set exactly the same as it is for *:443? (Just asking since for *:443 you have it showing as localhost but for *:80 you have it scrubbed to yourdomain.com)

Comment: @EdmCoff yes its the same

Comment: Did you see my answer? Did that help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen 80 was missing from the config

Answer (score 0):

To redirect use this on .htacess instead of virtualhost

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on          [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://antimalwareprogram.co%    {REQUEST_URI}     [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

And for first 2 lines if that doesn't work use this in replace of first 2 lines:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

That redirects www to root as well to not then delete  `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on          [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.   [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://antimalwareprogram.co%    {REQUEST_URI}     [R=301,L,NE]`

Note: Replace antimalwareprogram.co with your site URL
Keep % as that redirects to there current URL or it'll redirect to your home page and this redirect fixes http error as http won't exist!

#### HOPE THIS HELPED!